# Performant grid layout for tabular data

Tags: android

I have an app that need to show tabular data, but it's not a predictable schema. Some configurations will have 3 columns, some 5, some maybe more or less. In short, I can't have a pre-built layout...

I already have code that walks through the values pulled from the db and adds TableRows with TextViews for each element. It works well but is slow. I haven't had an ANR, but it's just a matter of time.

Are there other, better performing ways of loading these tables/grids? I've looked through some tutorials on ViewPager, but that seems to need a predictable number of pages.

If possible would love it to be "lazy", data would only be built for display as it's required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) provides a powerful, general purpose mechanism for continuous scrolling in either direction that recycles view elements (but allows both homogenous and heterogenous content) and is probably what you are looking for with respect to implementing dynamic tabs.

If you want to display a list of scrollable items where the elements are dynamically loaded and each row is recycled, then you probably want to use the [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) widget to accomplish it.